# Executar Graphviz (dot.exe) através de aplicação Java

Tags: java

Estou tentando gerar um grafo a partir de um arquivo .dot usando a ferramenta Graphviz. Para tal, dentro de uma aplicação Java, estou invocando o prompt de comando, navegando até a pasta de instalação do Graphviz e inserindo o comando, como segue abaixo:

```java
String cd= "cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.36\\bin";  
String comando = " dot -Tpng (...)saidaDot.dot -o (..)out.png ";  
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd.exe /C start cmd.exe /C "+cd+comando);
```

Onde **(...)** simboliza o diretório dos arquivos.

O prompt de comandos é aberto e fechado rapidamente e não obtive sucesso na geração do arquivo **out.png**.

Alguém tem idéia de onde possa estar meu erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre tente encapsular tudo que for ligações a programas externos em classes separadas.

O seu erro, é que não é possível usar o comando `cd` quando chamando o console em java.

Acredito que procura algo desta forma:

```
import java.io.*;

public class GraphViz {
    public void call(String arquivoDot, String arquivoPNG) {

        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String graphDir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.36\\bin\\dot.exe -Tpng ";
            String cmdString = graphDir + arquivoDot + " -o " + arquivoPNG;
            System.out.println(cmdString);
            Process pr = rt.exec(cmdString);
            BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String linha = null;
            while ((linha = entrada.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            pr.waitFor();
            if(pr.exitValue()!=0)
                System.out.println("Erro de saida " + pr.exitValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @Kyllopardiun, agora funcionou. Só tive que fazer uma alteração na linha:

`String cmdString = graphDir + arquivoDot + " -o " + arquivoPNG;`

Agora funcionou perfeitamente.